# performance counter doesn't work at all

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a question. 
When I am using visual studio and I am dragging the performance counter in the design, there is no list in the performance category name. If I enter Memory, and I start it, It will says that there is no Memory this kind of stuff. WHat should I do?[Here is the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgILm.png)

Here should be a list right? not in my visual studio...
[Another image here...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiaZF.png)

Comment: "CPU TEMP" is a wrong caption for usage of CPU+RAM - can you paste your code of this component into the post? And maybe some listenerMethods if you got some?

Comment: Consider using Perfmon.exe to discover performance counter categories and names.  Right-click the graph > Add Counters and you get a nice list.

Answer (score 0):

Here a short example using this component (in 1 small class):

1. Add a timer to your application
2. Create a onTick() Method (every 200ms should be enougth)
3. Use `System.Diagnostics` as import

---

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    // C0nstructor and stuff
    ....

    // Instance of a Counter
    PerformanceCounter performance = new PerformanceCounter ("Processor", "% Processor Time(Usage)", "_Total");

    // Ticking timer each X ms
    private void timer1_onTick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        label1.Text = "CPU-Usage: " + getCpuUsage();
    }

    // Getting the CPU-Usage value with symbol
    private String getCpuUsagePercent()
    {
        return performance.NextValue() + " %";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I have use like using System.Diagnostics;

Comment: But it doesn't work at all... What should I do??? I have use the timer1_onTick already, but when the label1 text come out like this
System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter 
when it should be a number